# Is there a statistical test to show that sugar liking flies tend to belong to bins where there are flies that also likes sugar and vice-versa?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, conditional-probability

I have about 900 flies that either like sugar or are neutral (about 50% in each group). However, on closer inspection I do notice a trend that sugar liking flies are from bins 1-10 (each bin has about 45 flies), while the neutral ones tend to be from 11-20 bins. I'm not sure why, but is there a statistical test I can do to show that sugar liking flies tend to belong to bins where there are flies that also likes sugar and vice-versa?

Comment: Hi @Ahdee, please could you describe in greater detail which question you want to answer from your data, what your hypotheses are, what "is about 50% percent in each group", what are the bins, how were the data collected? Perhaps even share a plot or a snapshot of the data so we can see what is going on?

Comment: If your hypothesis was generated by looking at the data you will be testing, your p-values will be meaningless.

Comment: hi @Momo sorry the lack of details.  Basically want I want to answer is this: I want to show that sugar preference is not due to chance and that it dependent on where the fly lives (bin).   If you choose one random fly from any bin (place where they live) and if that fly likes sugar you can predict with high probability its living mate also likes sugar.  Hope this makes sense ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have two categorical nominal variates: sugar appreciation and the bin. You can check association using Chi-Square test (with appropriate corrections, like Yates ones or Monte Carlo, if necessary) and then compare the chi-square residual (actual - expected)/expected^2 checking whether there is some pattern across bin and sugar appreciation of such residuals (a correspondence analysis might help too).